# Problem with UITextView

Tags: iphone, uitextview

I have a strange problem with trying to pass a string from one viewcontroller to another view controller if the string originates from a UITextview instead of UITextfield.  Both UITextview.text and UITextfield.text are of type NSString.

The following code takes either Textfield.text or Textview.text depending on the fieldType and puts it into a string called aString.

```
NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] init];
if (fieldType == 3) {
  aString = textView.text;
} else {
  aString = textField.text;
}
```

When I examine aString on either cases, I can see that it has successfully assigned the text into aString.

I then pass the string to the other view controller using this code.

```
[delegate updateSite:aString :editedFieldKey :fieldType];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This works fine if aString originated from textfield.text but nothing happens except the view controller is popped if aString was from textview.text

This is the code that takes aString and does stuff with it, however it doesn't even execute the first line of code "NSLog(@"Returned object: %@, field type:%@", aString,editedFieldKey);" if aString was from textview.text  Any help will be appreciated.

```
-(void)updateSite:(NSString *)aString :(NSString *)editedFieldKey :(int)fieldType  {
 NSLog(@"Returned object: %@, field type:%@", aString,editedFieldKey);

 switch (fieldType) {
  case 0: //string
   [aDiveSite setValue:aString forKey:editedFieldKey] ;
   NSLog(@"String set %@",[aDiveSite valueForKey:editedFieldKey] );
   break;
  case 1: //int
   [aDiveSite setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:aString.intValue] forKey:editedFieldKey];
   NSLog(@"Integer set");
   break;
  case 2: //float
   NSLog(@"Saving floating value");
   [aDiveSite setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:aString.floatValue] forKey:editedFieldKey];
   NSLog(@"Float set");
   break;
  case 3: //Text view
   [aDiveSite setValue:aString forKey:editedFieldKey];
   NSLog(@"Textview text saved");  
  default:        
   break;
 }
 [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: You're leaking aString. You should replace "NSString *aString = [[NSString alloc] init];" with "NSString *aString;"

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, sounds strange but I think your syntax is wrong:

```
[delegate updateSite:aString :editedFieldKey :fieldType];
```

should be

```
[delegate updateSite:aString editedFieldKey:fieldType];
```

and the method name:

```
-(void)updateSite:(NSString *)aString :(NSString *)editedFieldKey :(int)fieldType;
```

should be:

```
-(void)updateSite:(NSString *)aString (NSString *)editedFieldKey :(int)fieldType;
```

Can you try it?

Comment: The syntax [delegate updateSite:aString :editedFieldKey :fieldType] is actually correct - he didn't name the parameter. editedFieldKey is the actual parameter. Very confusing, though.
Also, the method name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've changed it to for editing textfield

```
[self.delegate editingViewController:self didTypeText:aString forKey:editedFieldKey forFieldType:fieldType];
```

and for textview I've created a separate controller that deals with it (and it works)

```
[self.delegate editTextViewController:self didEditText:textView.text forKey:editedFieldKey];
```